# Highlighting search keyword in Slickgrid

Tags: ajax, vue.js, slickgrid

I'm developing logs viewer web program with Vue.js
I receive log data with ajax and display it with Slickgrid.

What i need to do is highlighting keyword after searching.
I found some examples highlighting whole cells or row but couldn't find highlighting specific keyword in cell.

ex)When i search a word 'cat', slickgrid shows cells which include 'cat'. 
And i need to highlight the word 'cat' in the cell.

Anyone knows how to do this? or any examples??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a custom `formatter`. See [here](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters-event.html) for an example page. Make sure you're using the [6pac repo](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) - it's up to date, the MLeibman repo is unmaintained now.

Re highlighting a word, you'll need to return HTML from the formatter, and just have a special `span` to hilight the word, eg:

```
we will build a <span class="hilight">wall<span/>
```

It's a tricky business finding a full word, that is making sure it's not part of another word, if that's what you want eg.

```
did you buy the <span class="hilight">wall<span/>paper yet?
```

That's a whole 'nother Google search in itself.